# Okta login/sessionCookie?token=tokenValue is not working in IE 11 if okta site url is removed from the list of trusted sites

Tags: okta

I am using Okta API to inject cookie into the browser to create Okta session for a user when user logs in to the application. It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla browsers but it is breaking in IE 11 where Okta session was not getting created in this version of IE. 
We are using the below API to inject Okta session cookie into the browser : Add image tag with session cookie image URL(http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/session_cookie.html#add-image-tag-with-session-cookie-image-url) 
But after adding the Okta site URL into the list of trusted sites into the "Security" tab of IE 11 "Internet options", this API started working and Okta session was injected in IE 11. Can anyone help me 1in troubleshooting the issue? Does this API supports IE 11? As this is working fine in IE 9.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't have anything to do with the Okta API directly it has more to do with evolving browser security models.

When you attempt to establish the session using the hidden image it is seen as a 3rd party cookie (a cookie set by a website other than the site you are currently visiting)

In IE11 adding a site to the trusted sites does a number of things but specific to this topic it allows sites listed to establish 3rd party cookies.

From: http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/session_cookie.html#retrieving-a-session-cookie-with-a-hidden-image

> This flow is now deprecated as some major browser vendors such as Safari block cookies from 3rd-party sites by default. Please use an alternative flow as browser vendors are increasingly blocking cookies from 3rd party sites by default

-Matt